# Predict what users is typing by an option’s array

Tags: java

the problem is this:
I’ve an array that contains all word that the user can write and a method that is called every time that user digit a letter. I’ve to write the code that predict what the user is typing.

For example:

```
String[] temp = new String[] {“apple”, “orange”, “banana”, “Assomoir”}
```

When I digit “A” I want that this method return only Apple and Assomoir, but if I digit “AP” the method return only “Apple”.

I don’t know if I have to check with the loop  statements or exists already a built in a method that do all of this by its own.

Thank you for patience.

Comment: Use a list instead of an array, and filter the list using `String.startsWith(userInput)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following:

```
Arrays.stream(temp).filter(str -> str.startsWith("ap")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```